# What represents the loss or accuracy in training results in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I have two classes with 3 images each. I tried this code in Keras.

```
trainingDataGenerator = ImageDataGenerator()

trainGenerator = trainingDataGenerator.flow_from_directory(
                        trainingDataDir,
                        target_size=(28, 28),
                        batch_size = 1,
                        seed=7,
                        class_mode='binary',
                        )

FilterSize = (3,3)
inputShape = (imageWidth, imageHeight,3)

model = Sequential()
model.add (Conv2D(32, FilterSize, input_shape= inputShape))
model.add (Activation('relu'))
model.add ( MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer = 'rmsprop',
                metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit_generator(
        trainGenerator,
        steps_per_epoch=3,
        epochs=epochs)
```

**My Output:**

When I train this model, I get this output:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 2 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/1
3/3 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 5.3142 - acc: 0.6667
```

**My Question:**

I wonder how it determines the loss and accuracy and on what basis? (ie: loss: 5.3142 - acc: 0.6667 ). I have not given any validation image to validate the model to find accuracy and loss. **Does this loss, and accuracy is against the input image itself?**

In short, can we say something like this: "This model has accuracy of %, and loss of % without validation images"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **training** loss and accuracy is calculated not by comparing to validation data but rather by comparing the prediction of your neural network of sample x with the label y for that sample that you provide in your **training** set.

You initialize your neural network and (usually) set all weights to a random value with a certain deviation. After that you feed the features of your **training dataset** into your network, and let it "guess" the outcome aka the label that you have (if you do supervised learning like in your case).

Then your framework compares that guess with the actual label and calculates the error which it then backpropagates through your network thereby adjusting and improving all weights.

This works perfectly well without any validation data.

**Validation data** serves you to see the quality of your model (loss, accuracy etc.) by letting the model predict on unseen data. With that you get the so called **validation loss / accuracy** and with this information you tune your hyperparameters.

In a last step you use your **test data** to evaluate the final quality of your training.

Comment: You mean to say 1) get input x1, 2) train x1, 3) predict with x1, 4) find its accuracy/loss,  if these steps are right, then the final  accuracy/loss represents the avarage of all accuracy/loss

Comment: Not quite. 1. Feed in features `x`. 2. Let model guess the label `y` for `x`. 3. Compare guess with actual label for `x` 4. Calculate error, which is difference between guss and truth. 5. Backpropagate error. 6. Go back to 1. and redo in loop for all samples.

Comment: Sry, 1) first you train  the model with given x, and again 2) do the steps what you mentioned? is that so ?,  Did i miss something?

Comment: I think you might confuse features and labels. All your data in supervised learning has features (usually called X oder X_train) AND labels that you want the model to predict after training. For example the classes that you have (cats, dogs. etc.).

Comment: Training means: Input the features of your data into the model, let it guess / predict the label and then compare that to the truth (the actual label). This is done batch by batch. After each batch the error (difference between guess and truth) is backpropageted through the network. All this is done automatically by your framework (Keras, Tensorflow etc) during the training.

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply. I knew the different between feature and label :) . My confusion was here:  is validation is part of the training? ie: when feature is trained we get the prediction label, and checked against what is expected there by finding the loss/accuracy, then backpropagte to turn the error. is that correct?.

Comment: Validation can be part of your training (and it is a very good idea to do so) but it doesn´t have to be. Validation helps you to tune your hyperparameters especially if you do more than 1 epoch (which you usually want to do... :0). It helps you i.e. to see when your model overfits.

Comment: But validation also brings in a bias into your training because you as the "AI trainer" tune your model biased on that data set. Therefore final evaluation of the quality of the model is always done on a third data set (test data) which neither your model nor you have seen / used.

Comment: Sure petezurich. Thanks for your time.